# Understand Ring Buffer in async Logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

In async logger of log4j2  [mannual link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html)

default value of `log4j2.asyncLoggerConfigRingBufferSize` is `256 * 1024`

What does `256` and `1024` represent here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of slots in the ringbuffer needs to be a power of 2. This allows you to keep incrementing the counter and use a bitmask instead of modulo to get the array index from the counter.

For example, suppose we have a ringbuffer of size 4. Indexes `0` to `3` are valid indexes into the array. We want to avoid checking `index++; if (index > 3) { index = 0; }`.  In a tight loop this `if` check can slow things down. Can we avoid it?

Yes we can. We can just increment without checking, and when we get a value from the array we ignore all multiples of 4 (the size of the array). Often people use the *modulo* operation for this: `value = array[index % 4];`

```
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0
5 % 4 = 1
...
```

This works fine, but we can do better. The modulo operation works for any array size, but we chose the array size to be a power of two for a reason: bit masks! A bit mask can achieve the same thing, but much, much faster (about 25 times as fast).

How does this work? If the array is a power of two, we get its bit mask by subtracting one. We then use this mask when getting values from the array: `value = array[index & mask];`

For 4, the bit mask is 4-1=3. 3 in binary notation is `11`. Let’s look at the same example as before:

```
0011 & 0011 = 0011 (3 & 3 = 3)
1000 & 0011 = 0000 (4 & 3 = 0)
1001 & 0011 = 0001 (5 & 3 = 1)
...
```

So this does the same as taking the modulo but faster. Again, key point is that the array needs to be a multiple of 2.

Back to the question: The actual number of slots in the ringbuffer is `262144`. The documentation states `256 * 1024` to clarify that this is a power of 2.

Comment: what is the size of each slot?