# What is the size of a slot for log4j2.asyncLoggerRingBufferSize

Tags: java, log4j, buffer

The official doc explains the number of slots but does not say anything about the size of each slot:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncQueueFullPolicy.html

I searched around a bit but didn't get much information either.

SO: [Understand Ring Buffer in async Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887089/understand-ring-buffer-in-async-logger)

I am running a service which is logging huge stack traces (~50 lines) at a very high frequency leading to increase in overall latency. When I trim those stack traces, the latency decreases. I am logging at ~3MB/s and my logger ring buffer size is the default (256 * 1024). I wanted to know if I am filling up this queue leading to latency increase. What is the size of this queue in MBs if the setting is 256 * 1024 ?

Answer (score 1):

The latency may be caused by the Log4j 2 ThrowableProxy. This is currently under investigation, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2391

To find the actual size of the ringbuffer slots in memory, use the JOL tool (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/). From the JOL docs:

> ... using Unsafe, JVMTI, and Serviceability Agent (SA) heavily to decoder the actual object layout, footprint, and references. This makes JOL much more accurate than other tools ...